# lxc and sched_setscheduler

Tags: lxc, real-time, priority

I am trying to run an application inside a Centos container and needs to run in real time. I googled around and the suggestion was to add lxc.cap.keep = sys_nice.

After I did it, lxc-start complains that only lxc.cap.keep and lxc.keep.drop are not allowed side-by-side. Indeed, there are several lxc.cap.drop inside the global lxc config file.

How do I work around this?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to think `lxc.cap.keep` and `lxc.cap.drop` as the whitelist and the blacklist. If you can't use both, then instead of adding an entry to the whitelist, remove this entry from the blacklist. Indeed if you couldn't use the whitelist, that means the blacklist was in use. If the capability was removed, that means it was in the blacklist. So you have to redefine `lxc.cap.drop`.

All these configurations are in `/usr/share/lxc/config` but can vary slightly depending on (host) distribution or package version. Sometimes configuration files include other ones. These entries are all cumulative, so either the file has to be edited directly (beware upgrades...) or all of them have to be found to replace them.

- Easiest, for global replacement, the file `/usr/share/lxc/config/centos.common.conf` contains a line similar to:

  ```
  lxc.cap.drop = sys_module sys_nice sys_pacct
  ```

  remove the unwanted entry, so in this example replace with:

  ```
  lxc.cap.drop = sys_module sys_pacct
  ```
- To replace the configuration only in one container, find a way to enumerate all the dropped capabilities (some lxc verbose logs or any other method), and as the [manual](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/lxc/lxc.container.conf.5.en.html#CAPABILITIES) tells, use an entry with no value to cancel the blacklist, then "rebuild" it. An example if the host was also CentOS would be, after having removed `sys_nice`, to add this in the container's config, *after any include*:

  ```
  lxc.cap.drop = 
  lxc.cap.drop = mac_admin mac_override setfcap
  lxc.cap.drop = sys_module sys_pacct
  lxc.cap.drop = sys_rawio sys_time
  ```